# how would I keep my js code from working on certain subdomains

Tags: javascript

if I am trying to execute a warning to the console every time the url switched how would I exclude a website such as twitter.com/(username)/topics if the username is unique to the user every time

```
let lastUrl = location.href;
new MutationObserver(() => {
const url = location.href;
if (url !== lastUrl) {
lastUrl = url;

onUrlChange();



}

}).observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});

`window.__ttrExcludeUrls = ["https://twitter.com/explore",` "https://twitter.com/home","https://twitter.com/notifications", "https://twitter.com/messages", "https://twitter.com/i/bookmarks","https://twitter.com/i/moment_maker","https://.twitter.com/i/*"];



 function onUrlChange()
    {
      console.warn("URL changed", location.href);
    
      if(window.__ttrExcludeUrls.includes(location.href) == false)
      {
        console.log("THIS IS A TEST MESSAGE")
      }
      else
      {
        console.warn("WRONG URL")
      }
      if(location.href == "https://twitter.com/home")
      {
        console.warn("WRONG URL")
      }
      
    }
```

Comment: [`location.origin`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Location/origin), [`URL`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/URL).